# Как подключиться к бд на сервере

Tags: node.js, sql-server, backend, cors

БД - MS SQL, подключаюсь через node js. Суть проблемы заключается в том, что изначально для обучения создавал бд через sql server на своем ПК и успешно к ней подключался. Теперь нужно подключиться к БД, которая лежит на сервере и не могу понять как это сделать. Есть адрес сервера. Одна из проблем в том,что при попытке сделать fetch запрос появляется ошибка cors политики, понятно почему, но, если раньше, на своем сервере я устранял ее подключением cors модуля, то как решить эту проблему с БД на сервере? Может быть я вообще представляю себе все не так, просто первый опыт в бэкенде и хотелось бы понять как это должно быть устроено

Comment: "ошибка cors политики, понятно почему" - совершенно непонятно, в nodejs не существует никакого cors и такой ошибки возникнуть в принципе не может. Так что вы явно что-то не договариваете

Comment: А ещё я первый раз слышу, чтобы для подключения к БД использовали fetch - попытался погуглить эту тему, но ничего толкового не нашёл. Что у вас происходит вообще? Как вы используете fetch и каким чудом он у вас работает?

Comment: Я не использую fetch для подключения к БД, fetch я использую в реакте, чтобы получить данные, которые мне отдает сервер, написанный на nodejs (изначально он забирает их из ms sql). Ошибка cors политики возникает из-за того, что нельзя просто так подключиться с рандомного адреса к серверу - это небезопасно, модуль cors дает право на подключение. Его я и установил на свой локальный сервер.

Comment: Если у вас проблема с подключением к nodejs-серверу из браузера, значит так и нужно было написать в вопросе, а ms sql к этой проблеме вообще никакого отношения не имеет